I'm trying to plot a chart with results from an array all on the same chart, but I am getting separate charts, one for each element in the array
Update:
With the help of chatgpt I was able to solve this problem. The working code is as follows
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for array, pdc in zip(system.arrays, mc.results.dc):
    pdc['p_mp'].plot(ax=ax, label=f'{array.name}')
mc.results.ac.plot(ax=ax, label='Inverter')

ax.set_ylabel('System Output')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
#plt.ylabel('System Output')
#plt.legend()
#plt.show()
maxACp = max(mc.results.ac)
print(maxACp)

Original Question
I copied an example script from GitHub PVLIB which plots dc results for three solar arrays which make up part of a total PV system. It works fine until I change the module parameters to a set from the cecmodule database. The parameters used in the example are in a different format than the cecmodule table and pared down to only a few parameters. The dc results for power seem too low for a practical module but they do all plot on the same chart.
I replaced the module parameters to those looked up from the CECmodule database. Now I get the dc results which make sense but cannot get them to plot on the same chart. Below is the plotting part of the script.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for array, pdc in zip(system.arrays, mc.results.dc):
    pdc.plot(label=f'{array.name}')
mc.results.ac.plot(label='Inverter')
plt.ylabel('System Output')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

